# StructureMap MVC 5 html.Action Issue

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am trying to call an Action from my view using `@Html.Action("ActionName","controllerName")`. But my page fails to load with below error:

> A single instance of controller 'Web.Areas.Area1.Controllers.ActionController'
>   cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller
>   factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the
>   controller for each request.

I am using structure map for Dependency injection. Please help me what am i missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add

`x.For<{Your controller name}>().AlwaysUnique();`

in IoC.cs file. This should be done for every controller in your project.

For more details check [this link](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap.MVC5/issues/3).