# MVC3 - Return multiple Actions in Layout from layout controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two actions in my shared layout, main menu and footer that return PartialViews -

```
@Html.Action("MainMenu", "Layout", new { area = "" })    
...    
@Html.Action("FooterMenu", "Layout", new { area = "" })
```

But I am getting the error -

> "A single instance of controller 'Site.Controllers.LayoutController' cannot be used to handle multiple requests"

I am using `StructureMap` for dependency injection.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Do you have any `ActionFilters` in the controller. Are you using any DI framework?

Comment: No `ActionFilters`, StructureMap

Comment: OK, Its probably the configuration of `StructureMap`. The [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743215/structuremap-mvc-5-html-action-issue) possibly solves it (or at least should point you in the right direction)

Comment: Yes you were correct! Add `c.For<LayoutController>().AlwaysUnique();` to the IoC.cs file

Comment: If you edit your tags to include `c#` or `asp.net-mvc` I can close it as a dupe so others can be directed to the correct answer.